# react-quill image handler not rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-quill

```
import ReactQuill from "react-quill";
import Quill from "quill";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";

const AddPrice = () => {
const quillRef = useRef(null);
const [body, setBody] = useState("");

 const toolbarOptions = {
    toolbar: {
      container: [
        ["bold", "italic", "underline", "strike"],
        [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
        [{ align: [] }],
        [{ color: [] }, { background: [] }],
        ["image"],
        ["clean"],
      ],
      handlers: {
        image: () => {
          const input = document.createElement("input");
          input.setAttribute("type", "file");
          input.setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
          input.click();
          input.onchange = async () => {
            const file = input.files[0];
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("image", file);
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/upload", {
              method: "POST",
              body: formData,
              credentials: "include",
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            const quill = quillRef.current.getEditor();
            const range = quill.getSelection();
            const link = data.link;
            quill.editor.insertEmbed(
              range.index,
              "image",
              link,
              Quill.sources.USER
            );
            quill.editor.setSelection(range.index + 1, Quill.sources.SILENT);
          };
        },
      },
    },
  };

function handleChange(content, delta, source, editor) {
    setBody(editor.getContents());
  }

return (
<div id="container" className="w-full overflow-auto">
              <label className="flex flex-col  ">
                <p className="text-sm font-light">Descriere:</p>
                <ReactQuill
                  theme="snow"
                  ref={quillRef}
                  modules={toolbarOptions}
                  defaultValue={body}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
)
}
```

The given code is just snippets of my file!

I tried to insert a image to my react-quill by uploading it first to backend and then receiving a link with the file but it doesn't even render the rich text editor
The console sometimes gives me an error like : Undefined reading ('delta') and I also get a warning:
[Violation] Added synchronous DOM mutation listener to a 'DOMNodeInserted' event. Consider using MutationObserver to make the page more responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply and you have probably moved on from this problem.

Try wrapping toolbarOptions in useMemo as that resolved the issue for me.

```
const toolbarOptions = useMemo(() => ({
  toolbar: {
    // ...
  }
}), []);
```

Make sure you add the dependencies to useMemo.